# Remove default slide right animation on UITabBarController from "More" Menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a situation where I have enough tabs on a tab bar controller where the default system functionality has introduced the famous "..." more icon.

This is totally fine and I'm happy with the menu that is popped up when you tap it.

What I've noticed however is that a default transition occurs when selecting a item from the "more" menu (basically a slide right) to load the VC from the menu. Unfortunately this also introduces a lag on the accompanying slide "left" to get back to the menu.

My question is if this is default behaviour I have to live with or if this is something I can remove completely (ideally no transitions would be my preference).

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

**[The More Navigation Controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)**

The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. ***If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar.*** Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the remaining items.

Solution to your query:

1. Add only `Five` view controllers in your tabbar controller.
2. For last `Fifth` view controller, add more tabbar button icon (or any other image icon) manually and set a similar looking tableview (menu list).
3. Handle further navigation for remaining (`Sixth` onwards) view controllers, manually from tableview (row selection)

Storyboard Layout:

[image]

If you are looking for an alternate of `more` navigation, then you must customize tabbar controller and this may help you:

- [ZRScrollableTabBar](https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar): Scrollable tabbar items
- [IDScrollableTabBar](https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar): changing tabs with left and right swipe gestures on the tab bar.
- [JFATabBarController](https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController): Swipe tabs left and right

Ask me, if you want more clarification here.

Comment: Krunal - great approach - it's simple and solves the problem in a very standard way with UITableview.